# Стандарты кастомизации радио кнопок, чекбоксов и скорллбаров

Tags: css

Ребят, может кто знает, идет ли разработка стандартов в CSS по  кастомизации радио кнопок, чекбоксов и скорллбаров. Я имею ввиду именно стандарты, а не хаки или обходы, с помощью которых это делается сейчас.

Answer (score 2):

HTML 5 имеет достаточно много нововведение относительно кастомизации этих компонент. В CSS появились соответствующие изменения. Стандарты, как известно, ещё только разрабатываются, так что да, разработка стандартов продолжается.

Comment: шикарно. а не подкинете ссылочку где про них почитать можно?

Comment: И хотел бы вот что спросить, как я понял w3 ж не разрабатывает HTML5, а этим занимается WHATWG, но доки HTML5 есть на w3, дак на какие доки ориентироваться? проясните пожалуйста  если кто знает.